# inject data to a field by using load()

Tags: jquery, input

I'm trying to fill a field this way :

```
  $(button).click(function(){
      jquery(div).load('http://.../data.asp');
                data = $(div).html();
          $(input).val(data);
  });
```

It works but it needs a double-click to work completely ( `first-click` = div is filled , `second-click` = input is filled ) , how can I handle this ?

P.S : I don't want to use ajax. ( `get` )

Comment: use ajax `$.get(url,function(data){ $(div).html(data); })`

Comment: Use `.load()`'s callback.

Comment: I'm trying no to use Ajax.

Comment: load() is an ajax request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.load()` is asynchronous, it uses AJAX. Anything that depends on the returned data must be done in the callback function:

```
$(button).click(function() {
    $(div).load('URL', function(data) {
        $(input).val(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think `load` callback receives the `html` as a param... so we could use that

Comment: Well , thanks but something weird ! it works on firefox but not chrome .. why ?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would make a difference. Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put this stuff in the callback.

```
$(div).load(url,function(){  ... your code ...  });
```

But I would do this instead:

```
$.get(url,function(data){ ... code here ... });
```

They're both ajax requests, I prefer using `$.get()` for flexibility and not to get in the habit of using `.load()`